# Beginner's Mex Error - MatLab

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex

I am beginning to use the mex setup to call fortran files from matlab. What I am trying to do is call a fortran subroutine inside an m-file. From what I've read, I need to run:

`mex filename.f90`

However, when I do that, I get lots of error messages of the type:

```
error #5149: Illegal
character in statement label field  [s]
```

However, I am using a .f90 file that is supposedly correct (I got it from another source). Here are the first beginning lines of the fortran file:

```
subroutine mexFunction(nlhs,plhs,nrhs,prhs)
!--------------------------------------------------------------------
! Matlab gateway for sirff

 implicit none

 ! pointers to input/output data
 ! always take INTEGER*8, to let it work on 64-bit machines (SGI e.g.)
 ! 32-bit compilers will correct this to INTEGER*4, so don't worry about the
 ! warning(s) on this during compilation.
 integer(8) :: plhs(*), prhs(*)
```

I am a beginner to this, so bear with me please. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: An error like that suggests that the compiler is expecting fixed-form source (regardless of filename suffix).  Is it possible to show the compiler invocations or setup options?

Comment: Best place may be the mexopts file, but I'm afraid it's all a bit hazy for me.  [Someone more experienced may be more help.]

Comment: @francescalus - You are correct.  MATLAB doesn't compile `.f90` files and so the OP needs to edit his/her `mexopts`.

Comment: @user191919  - See this link and follow Step #4 - http://home.versatel.nl/tngoudsw/mexf90.html - Also, you aren't compiling your code properly.  You don't need the `[]` characters.  Leave those out, but make sure you follow the directions in the link to compile `.f90` files.  If the above link doesn't work, this may also help. https://sukhbinder.wordpress.com/2012/07/08/meshing-fortran-and-matlab-together-with-mex/

Comment: Thanks for the help, but all I could take os to alter the .f90 to .f and even so, I receive the same type of error... Any ideas as how I can proceed?

Comment: No sorry. I've never compiled FORTRAN code before. Suggest you ask MathWorks.

Comment: What is the best way to contact them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you are seeing is from the Intel compiler. Your Fortran mex file is being treated as fixed-format Fortran irrespective of the fact that you are using a `.f90` file extension (which traditionally signifies that the source is free format). You can easily recreate the error just with `ifort` itself:

```
> ifort -fixed filename.f90
filename.f90(1): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [s]
subroutine mexFunction(nlhs,plhs,nrhs,prhs)
^
```

You say that you renamed `filename.f90` to `filename.f`, but that does nothing to modify the source format (from free to fixed), so the error persists. Wikibooks describes [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Beginning_Fortran#Free_Form_and_Fixed_Form) how to make a fixed-format file. A good rule of thumb for what to do is to indent each line with 6 spaces and to change comment `!` symbols to `C`s. This should make your `mex` invocation succeed.

If you want to continue using free-format source you will need to modify your mex options to allow this. The MathWorks (UK) reference page for `mex` is http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html.

Comment: Another person suggesed I remove the /fixed format option in mexopts. Here is what my COMPFLAGS reads:
`COMPFLAGS="/nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc $INCLUDE  $COMPDEFINES"`
However it still does no work... How should I specify for the free form compiling?

Comment: The Intel manual for this is https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/525129. To paraphrase "Windows OS: /free. Specifies source files are in free format. Default: The source file format is determined from the file extension: files with an extension of .f90, .F90, or .i90 are free-format source files; files with an extension of .f, .for, .FOR, .ftn, or .i are fixed-format files."

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem. Actually all I needed wasto remove /fixed from the compiler flags. I had tried this. However, the compiler MatLab was using was inside an obscure folder which I hadn't altered.